# Deploying Laravel 5.4 to Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, production

I've got a real head-scratcher for you! I've been working on a Laravel 5.4 application for quite some time now and up until yesterday I had been able to:

1. **develop on my local** machine *[still works flawlessly]*,
2. **push my changes** to my BitBucket repo *[still okay here]*,
3. and would subsequently **pull those changes** to my shared hosting server (RedHat) *[still running smoothly]*,
4. I then **run my dependency managers** (npm and composer) to get the project in place and functional
5. there is some matter with **clearing various caches**:

   - php artisan view:clear
   - php artisan route:clear
   - php artisan cache:clear
   - composer dump-autoload
6. and finally **move my '/public' folder** to the web root and **update index.php** to point back to the 'bootstrap/autoload.php' in main project structure,
7. *I am aware there is likely another or several steps I am missing, but I am unsure what they are...*

All that being said, I've attempted to deploy a number of applications using Laravel lately and I always seem to run into the same issue come time to deploy an application to production. I've read **30+ tutorials** on the matter and nothing seems to explain the issue why my site isn't working any more.

- I've checked the error log file maintained by Apache, it's empty.

  - Was wondering if it's a permissions issue, doesn't seem to be the case (all folders set to 775 and files set to 664 as specified by various sources and owned by serverName:userName)
- Browser console simply shows a 500 server error.
- All I see if *"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."* twice.

  - There must be some way to show better error details (config debug setting already set to true)

Any suggestions at this point would be beneficial to send me looking in the right direction!

======= **UPDATES** =======

For the sake of thoroughness, and that this save others from severe headaches, I'll be posting actions taken here.

1. Following [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others?answertab=votes#tab-top) mentioned by @user123456 (permissions applies)
2. Generate new key for application
3. Run `php artisan config:clear`
4. Off to the races, answer to come!

Comment: Have you generated a new application key? You may need to run `php artisan key:generate` Also, ensure you have a working .env file.

Comment: .env is in place (even though I'm not using a database for this application), good suggestion. I'll try the key generation

Comment: It seems to have successfully generated the new key, though nothing seems to have changed unfortunately.

Comment: have you checked the error log maintained by laravel ?

Comment: The env is not just for db connections; laravel uses it for other things too such as the fact that it contains your application key. It's good if you already have it. This is likely a permissions issue so check this out and follow it to the latter again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others?answertab=votes#tab-top then see if you get a different error message

Comment: Look in storage/logs for the log file and see what the error is.  When you get a Whoops error, Laravel will log the error message.

Comment: @Devon, just found it! Thanks for the suggestion will post contents momentarily

Comment: @user123456 Thanks for the link, looking in to it now!

Comment: @user123456 I've following that tutorial line-by-line and the moment I connect my 'public/index.php' to the autoload all I can see is 'Whoops something went wrong'.
The only new entry in my error log is when 'bootstrap/autoload.php' wasn't linked properly.

Comment: Noticing this in my Laravel.log: production.ERROR: RuntimeException: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

Comment: Run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: You're almost there. Just generate another key and clear your cache.

Comment: @user123456 YOU SAINT! Thank you for taking the time to walk me through this. Did you want to provide an answer to get all the credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure you have a working .env file.

Once done, run `php artisan key:generate` to create a key for your application after which you should clear your application's cache as follows `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

I would never recommend using shared hosting for Laravel application. You will face lots of issues for permissions, composer and external dependencies. Instead, you can use cloud servers like DigitalOcean, Linode, vultr and deploy laravel application on them. If you don't know about linux and creating Stacks you can use Cloudways to deploy laravel.

https://dev.to/rizwan_saquib/deploy-laravel-application-on-cloud-easily-with-cloudways

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ShahrozeNawaz.